# Which is the method for getting list of all coupon codes in magento2?

Tags: magento2

Which is the method for getting list of all coupon codes in magento2 ?

Comment: Only need list of couponst? or anything else you need?

Answer (score 3):

Create File **Coupon.php** in app/code/Vendor/Module/Block

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Coupon extends Template
{    

   protected $_salesRuleCoupon;

   public function __construct(
        Context $context,        
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Coupon\CollectionFactory $salesRuleCoupon,
    )
    {    
        $this->_salesRuleCoupon = $salesRuleCoupon;
    }

     public function getCouponsList()
    {
       $collection= $this->_salesRuleCoupon->create();
       return $collection->getData();
    } 

}
```

2. Call above block function in your module template file

```
$coupons=$block->getCouponsList();
foreach($coupons as $coupon){
    echo $coupon['code'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ansar for replying. I am getting a blank screen after calling above code in template file.

Comment: did you use above code in same module  block and template?

Comment: Yes I had use in same module there is a folder DiscountCoupon inside block folder I putted Coupon.php in that folder modified namespace and than accessing it into my modules index.phtml file

Comment: I added above coupon code in controller now it is working but I need all details related to coupon code like description and other. Is there any method available for getting all details related to coupon ?

Comment: it should give you all detail of what coupons has

Comment: I am not getting cart paricerule details with this like name,description,date and other.

Comment: Hi @AnsarHusain.Thanks for this code.This code works fine for me.But I need to filter code based on the website.

Comment: @AnsarHusain I want to show only valid coupon code which can apply to the cart only not all the coupon codes